# Use tilde ~ in substitution inside neovim?

Tags: neovim, substitute

In vim 8.1 (tiny), I can use `~` in a substitution, but it won't work when using neovim 0.6.0.

For example, if I have a file with the text:

```
one two three
```

And I enter vim with "vim -u NONE -N", I can do `:%s/one/sub` to change the text into:

```
sub two three
```

And then use `:%s/two/~` to get:

```
sub sub three
```

And finally `:%s/three/~` to get:

```
sub sub sub
```

However, when using neovim by "nvim -u NONE", it seems to take the same `~` as an empty string.

Is this feature deprecated or something? It's not that it's really important for me, but neovim documentation still mentions it (at least inside /magic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. Try

```
:set icm=
:s/one/sub
:s/two/~
```

And it starts working even if `set icm&` back later.

I would be nice if someone raise an issue on Neovim github ASAP.

Comment: Ok, I already raised the issue

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz Oh, yes, I see. It looks like it was hanging for 1,5 years already. But, at least, it's gonna be fixed now.